# Forward/Stream express.js file upload directly to another API

Tags: node.js, express, axios

I have a frontend, which acts as a shield for Nextcloud.

In that frontend is a File Upload component. With that and axios I send a File to my express app which acts as "middle man" between the frontend and backend.

```
 await axios.put(
            process.env.VUE_APP_API_ENDPOINT + "files/upload",
            fileData,
            {
              headers: {
                "Content-Type": file.type,
                "j-og-name": file.name,
                "j-og-path": path,
              },
            }
          );
```

fileData is the raw fileData buffer from a FileReader.

In my backend, this function captures the /files/upload route

```
async function uploadFiles(req, res) {
  const { username, id } = req.decoded;
  let fileName = req.headers["j-og-name"];
  let filePath = req.headers["j-og-path"];
  let url = `${WEBDAV}/files/${username}/${filePath}${fileName}`;
  console.log(req.body, url);
  //i dont want to upload it AGAIN though!
  let response = await axios.request({
    method: "PUT",
    url: url,
    headers: {
      Authorization:
        "Basic " + Buffer.from(`${username}:${TEMP_PASS}`).toString("base64"),
    },
    data: req.body,
  });
  res.json({ status: "success", message: "" });
}
```

Right now i am just receiving it and THEN im sending/uploading the file to nextcloud. This makes the upload take "twice" as long as actually needed. How would I achieve my wanted behavior?
I have read into proxies and piping but haven't come to an actual result.